# How to make function wait with axios post request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios

I have a form and a button. My problem is:

- I'm using a boolean state as an indicator to play with URL link
- But the newUrl is being set to true before the axios request is bringing back respond and setting result to the returned json
  so when i set the newURL to true it ran to TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
- And await before the axios request yelling as well saying
  Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

  ```
  const MyComp = () =>{
  const [newUrl, setNewUrl] = useState(false);
  const inputText = useRef(null);
  let result;

  const fetchVideo = () => {
    const form = inputText.current;
    const inputValue = `${form['textToVideo'].value}`;
    dataVideo.timeline.scenes[0].text[1].val[0].text = inputValue;
    axios.post(
      'URL',jsonFILE,{
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            'Basic (authorization token)',
        }
      }
    ).then(res =>{ result = res;})
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    if(result){
      console.log(result.data.output.video[0].links.url)
      console.log(result.data)
    }
    setNewUrl(true)
    console.log(newUrl);
   }
  return (
    <section >
      <div>
        <div>           
           <div>
            <h1>Automated Video Ads For Your Shopify Store</h1>
            <h3>Enter your store discount below</h3>
            <div>
              <form ref={inputText}  >
                <input className="input" type="textContent" name="textToVideo"  placeholder="e.g Up to 30%&hellip;" />
              </form>
              <div>
                <button onClick={fetchVideo} className="button button-primary button-block button-shadow" type="submit">Show Me</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <HeroIllustration
            url={newUrl ? result.data.output.video[0].links.url : "PRIMARY_URL"}>                  
            </HeroIllustration>              
          </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  ```

  )
  }

Any advice?

Comment: First of all, how can there be the parsing error if you've not used `await` in your code snippet? Secondly, what kind of syntax is this: `**result = res;**`? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: With **xyz** he trying to make a part of code bold..That generally comes when you try to bold some part in your question..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an async function after all?

```
const MyComp = () =>{
const [newUrl, setNewUrl] = useState(false);
const inputText = useRef(null);
let result;

const fetchVideo = async () => {
  const form = inputText.current;
  const inputValue = `${form['textToVideo'].value}`;
  dataVideo.timeline.scenes[0].text[1].val[0].text = inputValue;
  await axios.post(
    'URL',jsonFILE,{
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          'Basic (authorization token)',
      }
    }
  )
```